# Telethon and Telebot libraries on Python. Do they work together?

Tags: telegram, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I have recently started writing a script based on **telethon**. The only thing it does is - **retriving videos, photos from channel/group, saving them to folder.**

So then I have decided to actually make a bot with command to run the telethon script which is going to download specific amount of files and send it back to user.

Sounds simple, however I ran to bunch of issues when tried to use telebot library to write a bot which then is going to run the telethon script. Makes no sense to post here errors I got, as I have tried too many things and got too many different errors.

**So my main question is Can Telebot run Telethon function as one is sync and the other async?**
If it can - are there any templates/example of such usage?
If it cannot - is there an example/possibility to write the bot with commands only on Telethon?

If non of the above is possible, are there any advices you can give me how can I implement the idea i described at first.

**Thanks everyone <3**

Comment: Telethon is one of the worst libraries I've ever used, it seems complete, is seems well documented but it is heavily buggy and very complex to use in multi threading environments.

Answer (score 2):

[See pyrogram library](https://docs.pyrogram.org/)

**I think you can write your own code with Pyrogram.**

Pyrogram supports asyncio and you can combine this library with [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/index.html) for automation task and also this library is very easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm really looking forward to hear some comments on my post.